# Connecting Mongodb Error

Tags: mongodb, rocket.chat

So I am trying to install RocketChat and MongoDB on an Ubuntu VM. I have configured everything correctly including using the appropriate IP address: 192.168.50.56 (which is commented out as it is supposed to be):

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  #bindIp: 192.168.50.56


#processManagement:

#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

replication:
        oplogSizeMB;
1
        replSetName: rs0
```

When I try connecting, I keep receiving this error:

```
@RocketChat:/etc$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v3.4.7
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2017-08-16T15:05:31.690-0400 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2017-08-16T15:05:31.690-0400 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want mongo to listen on multiple interfaces / ip addresses you need to list both ip addresses.

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,192.168.50.56

replication:
        oplogSizeMB: 1
        replSetName: rs0
```

The ip's can be comma seperated.

Then restart mongodb